# Combination of cards out of $52$ cards

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have questions. It is hard for me, so I really can not understand.

1. Pick $3$ cards which show all different numbers?
2. Pick $3$ cards which show all different suits?
3. Choose $3$ cards out of the $52$ cards. What is the probability that the product (multiplication) of the three numbers becomes even?
4. Choose $4$ cards out of the $52$ cards. What is the probability that the sum (addition) of the four numbers becomes $44$?
5. Choose $5$ cards out of the $52$ cards. What is the probability at the first card (number) is larger than the second card, which is larger than than the third card, which is larger than the fourth card, which is larger than the fifth card?

a. I only can figure out the 1st question until
$13$ suit 1 $= 13C3$
$13$ suit 2 $= 13C3$
$13$ suit 3 $= 13C3$ 
$13$ suit 4 $= 13C3$
But I think it need to add this arrangement of cards which took same suit but different number, example, $1$ diamond, $2$ heart, $3$ heart? Is it include to this combination, if so, I am stuck in here .

b. Diamonds $= 13$
Hearts $= 13$
Spades $= 13$
Clubs $= 13$
So we have to put each different suits ($4$ suits) in $3$ cards in $13$ types of numbers, in my opinion. This is the formula $4C3 \cdot 13$ CMIIW

3 - 6 I really don't have any idea.

I am really appreciate your helps. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't really understand part $1$ and $2$.You mean whats the probability to pick 3 with different numbers? or in how many ways it can happen? Please clarify and then I can give you some ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

A standard deck of $52$ cards has four suits, clubs, diamonds, hearts, and spades.  In each suit, there are $13$ ranks, $2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, J, Q, K, A$.

> In how many ways can three cards of different ranks be selected?

Choose three of the thirteen ranks.  For each of the selected ranks, choose one of the four suits.
$$\binom{13}{3}4^3$$

> In how many ways can three cards of different suits be selected?

Choose three of the four suits.  For each of the selected suits, choose one of the thirteen ranks.
$$\binom{4}{3}13^3$$

> If three cards are selected, what is the probability that the product of the three ranks becomes even?

The product will be even if at least one of the cards has an even rank.  Therefore, it can be found by subtracting the probability that all four cards have (not necessarily distinct) odd ranks from $1$.

If we treat a Jack as having rank $11$, a Queen as having rank $12$, and a King as having rank $13$, the answer will depend on whether we assign rank $1$ or rank $14$ to an Ace.

> If four cards are selected, what is the probability that the sum of the four ranks is $44$?

The denominator is the number of ways we can select four of the fifty-two cards in the deck.

Let $x_k$ be the rank of the $k$th card selected.  If we treat an Ace as having rank $1$, the number of favorable cases is the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 44$$
in the positive integers subject to the restrictions that $x_k \leq 13$ for $1 \leq k \leq 4$.

> If five cards are selected in order, what is the probability that the ranks are strictly decreasing?

The denominator is the number of ways we can select five cards from a fifty-two card deck.

The numerator is the number of ways we can choose five cards of different ranks since there is only one way to order them so that they are strictly decreasing.

Comment: wow, u are really superb. i'm trying to digest it now. maybe i'm not to smart enough to understand., apologize, i have questions,for Q 1&2, why it use ^3? for 3-6, so the answer is not really show the exact number? apologize and really appreciate for your time..

Comment: Since you only attempted the first two questions, I just provided a hint for the last four questions.  In the first problem, for each selected rank, there are four possible suits.  Hence, if the selected ranks are J, 7, and 5, we have four possible suits for the Jack, four possible suits for the 7, and four possible suits for the 5.  Hence, the number of three-card hands satisfying the given conditions is $$\binom{13}{3} \cdot 4 \cdot 4 \cdot 4 = \binom{13}{3}4^3$$  In the second problem, once the suits have been selected, we have $13$ choices of rank for each of the three selected suits.